# How to call ajax on success on document from another window?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I am doing this

```
function ajaxHelper(event, xhr, settings) {

}
$(document).ajaxComplete(ajaxHelper);
$(document).ajaxSuccess(ajaxHelper);
```

and this works for the same document, but then if I do this

```
var new_window = window.open("/bar.html");
$(new_window.document).ajaxComplete(ajaxHelper);
$(new_window.document).ajaxSuccess(ajaxHelper);
```

it does not seem to capture anything.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should be using the Ajax in the window and not the opener.

Comment: but I want to capture it from the parent, is there a way to do that?

Comment: you may want to wait for the new window to actually load before trying to attach event handlers to it. You can handle its load or DOMContentCreated events (natively or via jQuery) in the same way as the current window, I think. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open - this mentions that the loading happens asynchronously (as you might expect, if you think about it)

Comment: Yes you have to still reference jQuery in the window. The jQuery object in the opener is totally different than the one in the parent.

Comment: u mean like `new_window.$(new_window.document).ajaxSuccess...`?

Comment: something like that, but you have to wait until jQuery is actually loaded

Comment: ok that worked.

Answer (score -1):

The `window.open()` call is asynchronous and does not wait for the window to be opened.

Comment: Not sure how this actually answers the question.

Comment: It's easy:  the `new_window` variable does not *yet* point to an object that "exists [and is really ready for use ...] yet."  The window will be ready for use at some point in the future and an appropriate event will be generated at that time ... at which point calls to the other methods will work as expected.  The javascript console probably shows error messages right now when this code is executed as-written, but they probably don't show up anywhere else.  In JavaScript *everything* is asynchronous ...

Comment: Not really the issue, my comments under the post explain the real issue. So yes this is one part of many... And you really do not give a solution, just a comment on why it is not working.